# Open Graph Object title is not displayed in Action

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I create an object which title is defined. After it's posted, I use Object Browser to confirm it's title is being set correctly. Even though, action is displayed with a noun, not the title (as if object doesn't have a title defined).

What I expect to see: "reported fuel prices at Texaco"

What I get: "reported fuel prices at a station"

Code I'm using:

```
- (void)postToFacebook
{
id<FBOpenGraphObject> graphObject = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPost];

graphObject[@"title"] = @"My Title"
graphObject[@"type"] = @"myappnamespace:myobject";
graphObject[@"description"] = @"My Object Description";
graphObject[@"image"] = @[@{@"url": @"http://example.com", @"user_generated" : @"false"}];
graphObject[@"url"] = @"http://example.com";

[FBRequestConnection startForPostOpenGraphObject:graphObject
                               completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
 {
     NSString *objectId = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
     NSLog(@"Open Graph Object Posted: %@", objectId);

     // create an Open Graph action
     id<FBOpenGraphAction> action = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
     [action setObject:objectId forKey:@"myobject"];
     [action setObject:@"true" forKey:@"fb:explicitly_shared"];

     // create action referencing user owned object
     [FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"/me/myappnamespace:my_action" graphObject:action completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
         if(!error) {
             NSLog(@"Action successfully posted to facebook!");
         } else {
             // An error occurred
             NSLog(@"Encountered an error posting to Open Graph: %@", error);
         }
     }];
 }];
}
```

Comment: Hi there did you ever find a solution to your problem? I have had the same issue and never solved it...

Comment: Shayno, nothing yet :(